# Displaying images that were downloaded from Apple ODR

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, on-demand-resources

I have a set of images that I've added to the "cat-images" tag under Resource Tags in Xcode. In testing, I've done this:

```
let resourceRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: Set(["cat-images"]))
        resourceRequest.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources { (resourcesAvailable) in
            if resourcesAvailable {
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                resourceRequest.beginAccessingResources { (error) in
                    completion(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

This completes successfully, but then when I try do display one of the images from that set:

```
UIImage(named: "siamese.png").map { Image(uiImage: $0) }
```

The image cannot be found. Do I need to access the image in a different way if it's part of ODR? Does every single image in the folder need to have its own tag? Right now they're all tagged with "cat-images" but they don't have unique ODR tags.

I've also tried loading the image like this:

```
extension Image {
    static func loadFromODR(resourceName: String) -> Image? {
        let components = resourceName.split(separator: ".")
        let name = String(components[0])
        let ext = String(components[1])
        print("attempting odr image: \(name).\(ext)")
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: ext),
              let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) else {
            print("could not find: \(name).\(ext)")
            return nil
        }
        return Image(uiImage: image)
    }
}
```

but the image cannot be found.

Comment: From the documentation for `NSBundleResourceRequest`: *"The system will not attempt to purge the resources marked with a tag from on-device storage as long as at least one NSBundleResourceRequest object is managing the tag."* and *"Management ends after a call to endAccessingResources() or after the resource request object is deallocated."* and *"Methods in Bundle indicate to the system the relative importance of preserving a tag in memory after it is no longer in use."*.

Comment: So do I have to create copies of all the images that I want to use and store them in a class so they don't get lost?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used `NSBundleResourceRequest`. I'd at least try using `Bundle setPreservationPriority` and give the tag a high priority (1.0) and see if that helps keep them around longer.

Comment: You have to make sure `conditionallyBeginAccessingResources ` is done before trying to use the resource. it is easier to use the async await versions

Comment: having an NSBundleResourceRequest var in my view model seems to keep the images around and accessible (rather than using an ODRManager singleton)